# Deobfuscating Jar file [java]

Tags: java, decompiling

I am trying to make a game client that is similar to one already made so I tried to decompile the program to see how they did it to give myself ideas.  The issue is, when it was decompiled I found that it was fully obfuscated.  Now, I've read up on this and have listed the possible methods that people have said work:

-Refactoring with an IDE (Which IDE offers the best refactoring features?)

-Deobfuscate with a program like JOB

-Attempt to read and interpret the javabyte code

I used jd-gui to decompile the code.  A large amount of the classes are comprised mainly of code like this:

```
`// Byte code:
//   0: getstatic 171   com/Methodxe:Methodh    I
//   3: istore_3
//   4: aload_0`
```

What is the best way to go about this?  This is a bit out of my knowledge zone with refactoring and interpreting bytecode so I will need tips on how to go about this.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to write a game client by looking at the decompiled source to one is going to be like trying to write a novel in Russian by staring at an untranslated copy of *War and Peace*. That is, it's not going to be effective.

Comment: find someone at linkedin that has access to the source code and pay him some bribe :-) just kidding

Comment: If this Java game client happens to be Minecraft, you might be interested in the [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/page.php?4).  Much of the reverse-engineering work has been done already by modders.

Comment: There is no easy way to go about doing this.  Obfuscation is good at making it hard work to reverse engineer large applications.

Comment: Why not instead learn how to write a game from scratch? There are lots of good books on the subject available...